# Rasterize points by 'most frequent' in R

Tags: r, rasterizing

I have a series of spatial data points that I want to convert to a raster using the R function rasterize. The data I want represented is a factor value, so I want to represent the most frequently occuring value for each raster cell.

I have tried to write a funtion to get the mode, but it fails.

```
getmode <- function(v) {
uniqv <- unique(v)
uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}   

#run rasterize
test <- rasterize(best, rast, best$val, fun = getmode)
```

results in this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = na.rm)
```

Comment: Can you try by passing the argument name.  Also, your function name is `getmode`, is that the same as `Mode`?

Comment: getmode is the same as Mode, editted to correct. Not sure what you mean by try passing the argument name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal self-contained reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncols=20, nrows=10)
n <- 1000
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(n) * 360 - 180
y <- runif(n) * 180 - 90
xy <- cbind(x, y)
v <- sample(10, n, replace=TRUE)
```

Now add `...` to your function (see the documentation entry under `fun` in `?rasterize`):

```
getmode <- function(v, ...) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

And use it:

```
m <- rasterize(xy, r, v, getmode)
```